# Cookie test item in qual-e.appspot.com would fail at gold version(rc_11)

Tags: cobalt

When test with `https://qual-e.appspot.com`, the cookie item would fail at gold version(rc_11), but it would pass with qa version, from the [souce code](https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/rc_11/src/cobalt/dom/document.cc) ,
it seemed the gold version will not support cookie feature, and if I keep the code of gold the same with qa version, then it will pass the cookie test, so how to fix this failed item?

```
void Document::set_cookie(const std::string& cookie) {
#if defined(COBALT_BUILD_TYPE_GOLD)
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(cookie);
#else
  if (cookie_jar_) {
    cookie_jar_->SetCookie(url_as_gurl(), cookie);
  }
#endif
}
std::string Document::cookie() const {
#if defined(COBALT_BUILD_TYPE_GOLD)
  return std::string();
#else
  if (cookie_jar_) {
    return cookie_jar_->GetCookies(url_as_gurl());
  } else {
    DLOG(WARNING) << "Document has no cookie jar";
    return "";
  }
#endif
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we're going to change the Qual-E test case soon. Thanks for your patience.